# How can I fix this bug in answers package?

Tags: answers

I have just updated the answers package. I copy simple example

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{answers}
\Newassociation{sol}{Solution}{ans}
\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}
 \begin{document}
\Opensolutionfile{ans}[ans1]
\section{Problems}
 \begin{ex}
First exercise
 \begin{sol}
 First solution.
 \end{sol}
 \end{ex}
 \begin{ex}
 Second exercise
 \begin{sol}
 Second solution.
 \end{sol}
 \end{ex}
 \Closesolutionfile{ans}
 \section{Solutions}
 \input{ans1}
 \end{document}
```

When I compile, I got 
[image]

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Works here on TL2014. Is your whole distribution (not just `answers`) up to date?

Comment: Yes, I updated.

Comment: Please put `\listfiles` in your very first line, run the code again and edit the file list to your question.

Comment: There was a bug in one release of the package which should be fixed in the very latest one (`2014/08/08 v2.14`): you almost certainly need to update you TeX system.

Comment: I updated (2014/08/08 v2.14), but I can not fix  it. Then, I use old package.

Comment: We'll need to see your complete log, I think: I have no issue with an up-to-date TeX Live and the demo you've posted.